# What is the use of Identify (1,1) in synapse sql pool?

Tags: azure-synapse

Identity is different implementation in synapse and it cannot guarantee any base value or increment value.

What is the use of providing identity(1,1) in synapse sql pool?

Could you please answer my question

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of using an identity column in Synapse is to create a [unique key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-tables-identity#what-is-a-surrogate-key) for each row while consuming a minimal amount of resources. This assumes you don't turn use `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON` or reset the seed to override the default behavior. For the values to be unique, there is no requirement for a specific starting point or increment value. Including the `(<seed>, <increment>)`values in the command keeps the syntax consistent with SQL Server and Azure SQL.